# UTFgrid to shapefile

Tags: utfgrid

Is it possible to transform utf grid documents into shape files? I only have the utfgrid files and wish to use the shape files to render outlines on a map.

Comment: Please provide a link to a description of this format.  *The nice thing about standards is that there's so many to choose from*.

Comment: Version 1.0 of https://github.com/mapbox/utfgrid-spec

Comment: Please **edit** the question in response to comments requesting clarification.  As a new user, please be sure to take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  The answer to most every "Is it possible" question is "Yes, but..."  In this case the answer may be "but you need to code it yourself"; we'd need to know what GIS software or geodata development library you intend to use to able to be more specific.

Comment: not yet but I suspect that by Monday GeoTools will have UTFGrid read and write on master